# What magic Global Settings does with an SWF file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

It's been many a times, when my SWF doesnot run properly, and then after many tries, i just remember to

right click the swf ==> ( A dialog box "Flash Player Settings Manager" opens up ) ==> Advanced Tab ==> Trusted Loction Settings ( Here i set the file ,or the folder it resides in)

And hurrah! everything runs.

I wanna understand now, what is the magic here ?

1) What role does the trusted location settings play here.

2) This is only required by particular category of applications. ( As i believe not all SWFs are dependent upon it ) . What is this category. Why not other SWF apps  need to be specified in trusted location settings ?

Thanks
V.

Comment: You can read about different security sandboxes here (see local-trusted sandbox): http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3f.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c8f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's for loading files from the file system. A SWF isn't allowed to do it by default, but most IDEs handle that for you (i.e. write the policy files when you launch a SWF from them), so you don't see that much, unless you move the SWF outside the place it was originally compiled.